# Codelite C++ new project

Tags: c++, codelite

I am trying to learn C++ by following an Udemy course.

In the videos, when the teacher opens a new project end enters the main.cpp file, at the first line there is `#include <iostream>` and "hello world" code after that with `std::cout` and something.

However, when I open a new project, at the first line there is `#include <stdio.h>` and `printf` function like C.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Edit the source? BTW you will *never* learn C++ without a book and a teacher.

Comment: Maybe there are different templates?

Comment: Maybe you are choosing a `c` project instead of `c++`

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis what about source? Thanks for advice.

Comment: @drescherjm We both selected the default template but I am searching about it, thanks.

Comment: @drescherjm It is creating a cpp file but I am going to look at it, thanks.

Comment: delete the auto generated code and write your own.

Comment: Did you choose "Simple Executable (g++)" or "Simple Executable (gcc)" or are these not options anymore: [https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/QuickStart](https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/QuickStart)

Comment: it's really not a bad thing to write all the boiler plate (#include, int main() etc) yourlself, especially if you are learning

Comment: @bolov The reason behind my question is that maybe I am doing something wrong from the beginning. I am familiar with C btw.

Comment: @drescherjm I am selecting g++. I am beginning to think the template is different.

Comment: The example in the documentation shows `#include <stdio.h>` ...

Comment: @drescherjm however I was not asked to select a template. All I asked is that: https://imgur.com/a/0W49kJi

Comment: I found this: [https://d-fect.net/2018/07/12/changing-a-codelite-template/](https://d-fect.net/2018/07/12/changing-a-codelite-template/) not sure if its helpful. I don't use CodeLite. I use Visual Studio and rarely Qt-Creator or KDevelop.

Comment: Me, I'm still trying to figure out what makes a particular cod qualify as elite. Top grade in his or her school?

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you. I was already found this site, there is no template folder. However, I am accepting this template now.

Comment: @Efe Berkay Yitim.  This is simple.  In your open workspace create a new project and key the code in main.cpp you wish to use as a template.  Save it and right click on the project's name in the Workspace view. Select Save as template and you're done.  Any projects you create after that will start with a copy of that code.

Comment: @Bolov: If the wrong template is selected, it's fair to wonder whether something else may break later (e.g. compiler selector). Best find out what's going on now, even though you're going to end up write your code yourself.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Yes you can! It just takes more time looking at manuals and scrolling through SO. But it will give you the experience to learn something yourself, which you wouldn't have with a book/teacher.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov That's a great way to _mis_ learn. Don't be tempted. Use proper learning materials.

Comment: @Nikita no chance. Perhaps another language.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings So you suggest getting a new book/teacher every time you want to learn a new language/library or new features were added?

Comment: @NikitaDemodov For a new language, yes, of course... this is how people have properly learned things since the beginning of the written word. You _cannot_ learn C++ properly from Google and Stack Overflow, sorry. You have to actually read and study, like the good old days.

Comment: Manuals are usually OK for what they cover. Stack Overflow is usually OK, if you know the terminology to find the right questions. The internet as a whole? Bad idea. But some books are bad, some teachers are bad, some of everything is bad. What you really want to do is find the domain experts and follow their tutorials or recommended reference materials. But you need to know enough of the background material to find and recognize those domain experts in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new project. Write whatever you want into it, then rigth click it and select the option called "Save as Template". From there you can name it and save it under user templates. Then whenever you want to create a new project you can select that template and it will come up just like you wanted.